# instantiate @ViewChild on AfterViewInit angular 2

Tags: angular, viewchild

i was trying to make reference to a dynamic template which i add  during the usage of the app but the value of view child is always undefined , so i was asking can i instantiate it on After View Init ?
thanks .
i'm using dragula library and i want to create a component when i drop a dragged element , the problem is that the component to be created is used in many components that are loaded  in the same page so i want to inject a 'cabled ' html element with a different local variable in the on in it and i want to use the view child to have access to that child later .

```js
@ViewChild('viewerheader',{ read: ViewContainerRef }) viewerContainer;
  constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService,private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    dragulaService.drop.subscribe((value) => {
      //console.log('dropped header sunbscribed' , value ) ;
      this.onDrop(value.slice(1));

    }); 
  }

ngOnInit() { 
  this.element = document.getElementById('sectionheader0');
       console.log ('got element' ,this.element );
       $(this.element).append('<ng-template  #viewerHeader></ng-  template>');
     }
private onDrop(args) {
    let [e, target ,source,el] = args;
    this.createComponent(e.id);
  }
  
  
createComponent(id : string){
    //this.viewerContainer.clear(); 
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(Viewer);
    const componentRef = this.viewerContainer.createComponent(factory);
    componentRef.instance.id = id;
    console.log('create Compnent called + Id' + id);
    
    console.log('create component' + id );
    }
```

Comment: Please add some code so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Please try this method.
Subscribe to changes of ViewChild in AfterViewInit hook.

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.viewerContainer.changes.subscribe(() => {
   // do anything here since you are sure that view child is defined

     });;
  }
```